# Method returning redirect to itself - localhost redirected too many times

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a method like so:

```
// GET: Pages Index
        public ActionResult Index(string page = "")
        {
            if (page == "")
                page = "home";

            PagesVM pageVM;
            PagesDTO pageDTO;

            Db db = new Db();

            if (!db.Pages.Any(row => row.Slug.Equals(page)))
                return RedirectToAction("Index");

            ...
        }
```

If I go to `mydomain/somepage` and that page exists, it works fine, but if the page does not exist it redirect to itself but too many times, I don't get why because when it redirects to itself `page` should become `home` and it should work but it keeps redirecting too many times.

Any way to avoid this and basically keep it all in one method?

Comment: Have you diagnosed *exactly* what it's redirecting to? Are you sure there *is* a page with a row slug of "home"?

Comment: Not sure what exactly it is redirecting to, how to check? And yes I am sure of "home".

Comment: Well, how do you normally perform diagnostics? You could use a debugger and set a breakpoint, you could add logging, you could look at the existing HTTP logs... if currently you have no way of diagnosing how your app is behaving, that's probably the first thing to fix, as it'll be useful *well* beyond this one problem.

Comment: I know that I thought you meant something more. Page is what I tiold it be, `somepage` in this case, and it is returning to index as expected, there is nothing more to it.

Comment: Well there is, because apparently it's redirecting again... so you need to find out what's happening in that second request.

Comment: Yes, I keep hitting continue and it keeps redirecting and page is still what I told it to be initially, which is weird.

Comment: That information is what I was encouraging you to find out - you should put it in the question. I suspect that when you don't specify any route values, it uses the existing ones. Try `return RedirectToAction("Index", "");` or possibly `return RedirectToAction("Index", new { page ="" }`); to *explicitly* provide the relevant route information.

Comment: That gives me a routing problem, I will try different overloads later and see if something works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting a break point in at your return statement and running in debug mode, hover over the "page" variable, when the debugger stops the code execution and confirm its value is "home" at the moment the page redirects.

If this is the case, then the issue lies in either your LINQ statement or your data set. Make sure Pages table contains a slug value of home.

Edit:

Replacing

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

With either

```
return RedirectToAction("Index",new { page = "" });
```

Or

```
return RedirectToAction("Index",new { page = "home" });
```

Solves this issue.

Comment: What do you mean? Just before it returns there is this f (!db.Pages.Any(row => row.Slug.Equals(page))) , and in that line page is of course whatever I told it to be, in this case `somepage` which does not exist, hence it redirects. Why would it be home it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question a bit, sorry about that. Is the issue that the self redirect is keeping the parameter? e.g. 
If you replace

Comment: return RedirectToAction("Index");

with 

return RedirectToAction("Index",new { page = "home" }); 

Does that solve the issue?

Comment: It does indeed give me the home page but then the url is `mysite.com/home` which is ridiculous BUT with `{ page = "" }` it's perfect! You can post both variations as the answer and I will accept, thanks!

Comment: Glad it works for you, I've edited my answer accordingly